# On click submit go to an url from field

Tags: php, forms, field

I have a simple form:

```
<form class="form-contact-warp form-calc-ship cb-form" action="javascript:redirect();">
  <input class="form-control" required="" id="textBox" type="text" name="code" size="15"  placeholder="USI-TECH affiliate ID">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-main-color btn-block"> Create page</button>
</form>
```

If I put in input field the text `daniel`, I want to append a link.

Example:

I put `daniel` in and I click submit. I want to appear below the link
`www.example.com/daniel` and the text `This is your link`.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "I want to appear below the link"? Let me get this straight, you want to take the input and redirect to a page as you mentioned in the example link? You'd most likely have to check if the folder and file exist or not, then create them (or rather copy them from a template file) if necessary and then redirect... but is that what you need? What about the text, where do you want it if you're going to redirect? I'd say post what you've tried so far and tell us what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to use jQuery or JavaScript by itself:

```
<form class="form-contact-warp form-calc-ship cb-form" action="" method="post">
  <input class="form-control" required="" id="textBox" type="text" name="code" size="15"  placeholder="USI-TECH affiliate ID">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-main-color btn-block"> Create page</button>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
<!-- add jquery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#response').html('This is your link:<br />http://www.example.com/'+encodeURI($('#textBox').val()));
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is a jQuery demo found at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unns36nc/)

Here is the same thing, only it changes [when you type](https://jsfiddle.net/unns36nc/1/).

If you want to use purely PHP, you need to check something has been submitted:

```
<form class="form-contact-warp form-calc-ship cb-form" action="" method="post">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" size="15"  placeholder="USI-TECH affiliate ID">
  <input type="submit" class="btn-main-color btn-block" value="Create page" />
</form>

<?php
# Check if there is a post
if(!empty($_POST['code'])) {
    # You want to make sure you remove possible html and covert the string to a url.
    echo 'This is your link:<br />http://www.example.com/'.urlencode(trim(strip_tags($_POST['code'])));
}
```